# no update of parameters using multirootsolver

Tags: c, gsl, nonlinear-optimization

I am currently trying to write a code to solve a non linear system of equations. I am using the functions of the gsl library, more specifically the multiroot_fdf_solver.
My problem is that it currently doesn't want to converge. More specifically, I have the following behavior:

-if my initial conditions are close to the result, the gsl_multiroot_fdf_solver_iterate does not update the parameters at all. I tried to display the results on the different steps, and I have for all the parameters dx = NaN (I think this quite srange), the status of gsl_multiroot_fdf_solver_iterate is "success" and the status of gsl_multiroot_test_residual is "the iteration has not converged yet"

-the parameters are only updated if my initial conditions are really far from the expected result. Obvisously in this case it does not converge to the right values.

I have already checked multiple times the expression of my function and my Jacobian, and they seem good.

I have to precise that my Jacobian (and my system as well) are quite complicated expression with many trigonometric function.

Would you have any idea of what it could be? Is it possible that if the expression of the Jacobian is too complicated, it has troubles to compute it?
Thank you in advance for your answers, I am really stucked at this point.

Comment: For such a specific question on such a specific library with non-trivial mathematical concepts, you are probably going to have better luck asking for help at the GSL help list.  https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-gsl.  If you think it is a programming-specific problem you are encountering, you'd need to show some code to give anyone a chance at helping.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. At this point I think I will try to use the GSL help list (I was not aware of its existence). I will post the answer here if positive. Thanks again.